# How to separate html from js?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wrote the program based on the tutorial and now I want to separate the html code from js but it doesn't work. Some lines of js code have a connection to the database sent as paramentr and after separating the html codes from js it doesn't work ... anyone have any idea? Here I put the entire index.php file with js code below. In this version it works, however, when I separate it into a separate js file it doesn't work anymore. At the top of the code are the function declarations in php which are then used in the js code

```
<?php
//index.php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['zalogowany']))
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bukowski2", "root", "");

//Utworzenie tablicy walut

 $userArray = array();
 $query = "SELECT * FROM currencies";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $i=0;
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $userArray[$i]=$row["currency"];
  $i=$i+1;
 }

function fill_unit_select_box0($connect)
{ 
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM item_name";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option  value="'.$row["item_name"].'">'.$row["item_name"].'</option>';
 }

 return $output;
}

function fill_unit_select_box1($connect)
{ 
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM sizes";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option  value="'.$row["sizes"].'">'.$row["sizes"].'</option>';
 }

 return $output;
}


function fill_unit_select_box2($connect)
{ 
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option  value="'.$row["user"].'">'.$row["user"].'</option>';
 }

 return $output;
}

function fill_unit_select_box3($connect)
{ 
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM currencies";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option  value="'.$row["currency"].'">'.$row["currency"].'</option>';
 }

 return $output;
}

function create_currencies_table($connect){
     $userArray = array();
     $query = "SELECT * FROM currencies";
     $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute();
     $result = $statement->fetchAll();
     $i=0;
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
      $userArray[$i]=$row["currency"];
      $i=$i+1;
     }
     return json_encode($userArray);
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Formularz sprzedaży</title>
  <script src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js.js" defer></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <?php
    $_SESSION['sales_date']=date('Y-m-d');
    echo '<p class="logged">Zalogowany: '.$_SESSION['user'].' | '.$_SESSION['sales_date'].' |  [ <a href="logout.php">Wyloguj się</a> ]</p>';
    ?>

  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center">Formularz sprzedaży</h3><br />
   <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <div class="table-repsonsive">
     <span id="error"></span>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width=70>Lp.</th>    
                <th width=300>Nazwa i kolor produktu</th>
                <th width=100>Rozmiar</th>
                <th width=100>Cena PLN</th>
                <th width=100>KARTA</th>
                <th width=200>Inna waluta1</th><!--Inna waluta czyli kolumna w której mamy 2 komórki   -->
                <th width=150>Od</th>
                <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Dodaj</span></button></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">SUMA</th>
                <th width=100><input readonly value=0 type="text" class="form-control" id="total_amount_pln"/></th>
                <th width=100><input readonly value=0 type="text" class="form-control" id="total_cart_payment"/></th>
                <th width=200><input readonly value=0 type="text" class="form-control" id="total_amount_oc"/></th><!--Kolumna w której mamy 2 komórki  -->
                <th colspan="2"> </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
     <div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Wyślij" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>

//deklaracja i definicja funkcji dokonującej zmian w polu inna waluta//
function change_oc(){
    var array1=[],array2=[],array3=[],array4=[],array5=[];
    var x=0,y=0,z=0,m=0,j=0,k=0; //iteratory
    var suma=0;
    var string_suma;

    $('.total_oc1').each(function(){
        array1[x]=$(this).val();
        x++;
        z++;
    });
    $('.total_oc2').each(function(){
        array2[y]=$(this).val();
        y++;
    });
    currency_table.forEach(function(index){
        suma=0;
        for(var i=0;i<z;i++){
            if(array2[i]==index){
                num=array1[i];
                suma+=~~parseInt(num);
            }   
        }   
        array3[m]=suma;
        m++;
    });
    currency_table.forEach(function(index2){
        if(array3[j]==0){
            array4[j]=0;
        }else{
            array4[j]=array3[j]+index2;
        }
        j++
    }); 
    array4.forEach(function(index3){
        if(index3!=0){
            array5[k]=index3;
            k++;
        }
    });
    string_suma=array5.join("+");
    $('#total_amount_oc').val((string_suma)||0);
}

//deklaracja i definicja funkcji dokonującej zmian w polu cena PLN//
function total_pln(){
    var suma=0;
    $('.total_pln').each(function(){
        num=($(this).val()||0);
        suma+=parseInt(num);
     });
     if (suma!=0)
        suma=suma+"zł";
    else
        suma=suma;
     $('#total_amount_pln').val((suma)||0);
}

//deklaracja i definicja funkcji dokonującej zmian w polu cena KARTA//
function total_cart_payment(){
    var suma=0;
    $('.cart_payment').each(function(){
        num=($(this).val()||0);
        suma+=parseInt(num);
     });
     if (suma!=0)
        suma=suma+"zł";
    else
        suma=suma;
     $('#total_cart_payment').val((suma)||0);
 }


//deklaracja i definicja funkcji usuwającej wiersz//
function remove_row(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    var count=0;
    $('.lp').each(function(){
        count=count+1;
        $(this).text(count);
        change_oc();
    });
}
//deklaracja i definicja funkcji wysyłającej dane//

function submit (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var error = '';
    var count_item_name_color=1; 
    var count_item_price=1; 

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    if(error == ''){
        $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            success:function(data){
                if(data == 'ok'){
                    $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                    $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Dane zostały wysłane</div>');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
    }
}

//deklaracja i definicja funkcji dodającej wiersz do tableli//
function add_row(){
    var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td class="lp"></td>';
    html += '<td><select required name="item_name_color[]" class="form-control item_name_color"><option value=""><?php echo fill_unit_select_box0($connect); ?></option></select></td>';
    html += '<td><select required name="size_id[]" class="form-control size_id"><option value=""><?php echo fill_unit_select_box1($connect); ?></option></select></td>';
    html += '<td><input required type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" value=0  autocomplete="off" name="total_pln[]" class="form-control total_pln" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input required type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" value=0  autocomplete="off" name="total_cart_payment[]" class="form-control cart_payment" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input style="width:45%; display: inline-block; margin-right:5px;" required type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" value=0  autocomplete="off" name="total_oc1[]" class="form-control total_oc1" /><select srequired style=" display: inline-block; width:45%;" name="total_oc2[]" class="form-control total_oc2"><option value=""><?php echo fill_unit_select_box3($connect); ?></option></select></td>'; 
    html += '<td><select srequired name="item_from[]" class="form-control item_from"><option value=""><?php echo fill_unit_select_box2($connect); ?></option></select></td>';
    html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="remove btn btn-danger btn-sm "><span>Usuń</span></button></td></tr>';

    $('#item_table').append(html);
    var count=0;
    $('.lp').each(function(){
    count=count+1;
    $(this).text(count);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

//dodawanie wiersza do tableli//
$(document).on('click', '.add', add_row);

//Dokananie obliczenia po wprowadzeniu zmian w polu cana PLN//
$(document).on('keyup','.total_pln',total_pln);

//Dokananie obliczenia po wprowadzeniu zmian w polu cana PLN//
 $(document).on('keyup','.cart_payment',total_cart_payment);

//Utworzenie tablicy walut która będzie użyta dla funkcji change_oc//
currency_table = <?php echo json_encode($userArray); ?>;

//Dokananie obliczenia po wprowadzeniu zmian w polach inna waluta//
$(document).on('keyup click','.total_oc1,.total_oc2',change_oc);

//Usunięcie wiersza//
$(document).on('click','.remove',remove_row);

//Wysłanie danych//
$('#insert_form').on('submit',submit);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're not yet aware, PHP runs on the server, before the server sends HTML, CSS and JavaScript to the browser. The PHP and the JavaScript never interact! So with that said, I'm gonna guess that this line is giving you trouble:

currency_table = < ?php echo json_encode($userArray); ? >;

because it looks as though it's in your JavaScript! It will work if this PHP/JavaScript thing is left in your HTML, between script tags. Looks to me like the rest of the JavaScript can be separated. Give it a try!